# select query through with json data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json, parsing

I am trying to fetch the data from the database where the value is inserted in JSON format, I read the various threads available online but these all are not worked and match the query or bit tough to implement for me as a beginner.
Please help is this possible to fetch the data if the saving this formate in DB though MySQL query?

I am trying to do this from last 2 days but all functions and login was not worked.
Please help.

| ID | log_in |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"in_dt":"2020-01-01","in_by":namehere}] |
| 2 | [{"in_dt":"2020-01-01","in_by":namehere}] |
| 3 | [{"in_dt":"2020-01-02","in_by":namehere}] |
| 4 | [{"in_dt":"2020-01-05","in_by":namehere}] |

what I am trying..

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `table` 
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(JSON.parse(`log_in`.`in_dt`,'%Y-%m-%d')) 
           BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-05'
```

but it not working..

Comment: I think `namehere` is just a representation but not a real value as not being quoted, isn't it?

Comment: yes, this is for representation and the value being in quotes. sorry for the typos

Comment: Btw, What's the data type of the `log_in` column, `VARCHAR` or `JSON` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can rather use `JSON_EXTRACT()` function after quoting the values of the `log_in` column such as

```
SELECT *
  FROM `table` 
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(JSON_EXTRACT(log_in,'$[0].in_dt'),'%Y-%m-%d')
           BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-05'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b09ece76be493d8602ff6b3b82cb842b)</kbd>

If the data type of the log_in column is `JSON` instead of `VARCHAR`, the use an explicit casting for the SELECT-list such as

```
SELECT ID, CAST(log_in AS JSON) AS log_in
```

Comment: no output comes

Comment: Hi @Satyam . Can you please explain what have you tried and got within a fiddle(with some sample data of course), and share link of the fiddle as the comment ...

Comment: it is not working on my myphpadmin but it working in online fiddle or SQL IDE

Comment: What error(s) do you get @Satyam ?

Comment: no any error comes only empty row get..